# Нужно вытащить слово из URL

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, url

Есть к примеру УРЛ "https://test.com/images/word/test.jpg" нужно вытащить слово "word". В даном случае предпоследнее слово.

Незнаю как написать выражение

Comment: слова могут быть разные?

Answer (score 1):

Если формат всегда такой же, то так примерно:

```
$route = explode('/', $url, -1);
$word = array_pop($route);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Если формат всегда такой же, то так примерно:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^ a-zа-яё\d]/ui', '', $url);
echo $str[1];
```

Если формат меняется, а вам нужно найти именно word,
тогда:

```
$key = array_search('word', $str);
echo $key
```

если true, то выдаст ключ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте функцию

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)
```